# How do I properly use these variables in a separate function in Go?

Tags: go

Apologies for what is likely a very elementary question.

I'm using `http`'s `listenAndServe`, and it calls the following function:

```
func library(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request)
```

A lot of the code contained in that function applies elsewhere, so I wanted to bring it out into another function, such as:

```
func commonFunction(doThing bool, writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request)
```

But is that function header for `commonFunction` correct if I'm passing those two variables from `library` into it?

Would I call it as `commonFunction(true, writer, request)`?

I'm mostly confused if I should be passing pointers to these variables? It would make sense not to for `http.Request` as it's already a pointer, but what about `http.ResponseWriter`, surely I don't want to recreate the variable?

Answer (score 3):

Your signature looks fine. One part many people overlook when they first start doing web work in Go is that the `writer http.ResponseWriter` is an interface value. In Go interface values are reference types meaning that the `writer` variable you're being passed already internally contains a pointer to the concrete value that's satisfying that interface. You can feel free to pass your `writer` on to `commonFunction` and it's already a reference.